# MVC 5 App with Google OAuth2 Sign-on issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am following [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) to login using a google account. However even after installing the latest version of entity framework to the the project and also the latest versions of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, I am still getting an error at these lines

app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
   app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

The first error is that my ApplicationDbContext does not contain a definition for Create. Now how is this possible? Or is this something I have to implement myself in the ApplicationDbContext class? If yes, wont those changes be lost when I reacreate the edmx file?

The second problem is there is no ApplicationUserManager class present. What will have to be the definition of this class?

Am I missing some references or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need those lines in your code, that article is probably using an old version of the template. All you need to do is copy the Google AppId and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. It worked without as well. Those two lines looked important from the comments in the article. The question now is how to ensure a single instance per request? or has that been taken care of by the newer template as well?

Comment: Converted to an answer then. Single instance of what?

Comment: Single instance of the dbcontext and user manager..

Comment: Why do you want to ensure single instance?

Comment: better use of resources?.. I guessing. Thats what I understood of that line in the example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54062/discussion-between-davidg-and-user20358).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need those lines in your code, that article is using an old version of the template. All you need to do is copy the Google AppId and it should work